# Python - Append Help - String & list

Tags: python, append

Another append question... This is my code:

```
def s(xs,n,m):
    t = []
    while n < m:
        n += 2
        t.append(xs[n])
    return t
```

When I evaluate the following:

```
x = s('African', 0, 3)
```

Why does it return this?:

```
['r', 'c']
```

Comment: Ok, I gave an explanation below there.

Comment: Thanks Nemoden !, sry abt tht explanation AGAIN..., i am scared of using the wrong terms/words to explain python... :)

Answer (score 3):

```
while n < m:
    n += 2 # at this point n = 2 because you've passed 0
    t.append(xs[n]) # you append r to t since xs[2] = r
```

but n < m still, so next iteration:

```
while n < m:
    n += 2 # at this point n = 4
    t.append(xs[n]) # you append c to t since xs[4] = c
```

now n > m, so the function returns `['r', 'c']`. Everything is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so line-by-line...

Your call looks like this:

```
x = s('African', 0, 3)
```

so what happens is:

1. Step 1. - initial assignement

   ```
   def s(xs,n,m):
   ```

   `xs='African'`, `n=0` and `m=3` and then:

   ```
   t = []
   ```

   (so, empty list `t` is introduced).
2. Step 2. - loop

   1. Then the following condition is evaluated:

      ```
      while n < m:
      ```

      to `True`, because `0 < 3`.
   2. And then `n` is increased:

      ```
      n += 2
      ```

      so it is now equal to `2`.
   3. Then the appropriate element is appended to the empty `t` list:

      ```
      t.append(xs[n])
      ```

      and this element is "`r`", because `xs[2] == 'r'`.
   4. Then `n < m` condition is again evaluated to `True` (because `2 < 3`), so the loop executes again:

      ```
      n += 2
      ```

      and `n` is now equal to `4`.
   5. Then appropriate char from `xs` string is appended to `t` list (which already has one element, `r`, as we mentioned above).

      ```
      t.append(xs[n])
      ```

      and this element is "`c`" (because `xs[4]` is exactly "`c`").
   6. Then condition for `while` loop is again evaluated, but this time to `False` (because `4 < 3` is not true), so the loop stops executing...
3. (Step 3. - after the loop) ...and the program flow goes to the final statement of the function, which is:

   ```
   return t
   ```

And `t` returns the list we filled with two elements - as a result, the function returns list `['r', 'c']`.

Is it clear enough? Did it help?

Comment: Silly me, I had n = 3 for some reason, its late for me i must be getting blind !, hope this is useful for anyone in the future, as stupid as me... lol

Comment: @jetair: It may not be useful, as this is quite localized and containes basic programming knowledge.

Comment: can i delete it then ? would be silly to have it here and waste space...?

Comment: It is your decision, but your question is not invaluable as some from previous 8169248 entries (your question has number of 8169249). Don't be afraid of asking questions, just put as much effort as possible in solving them before you ask them to others.